# Hardware Comparison Resources

Tags: computer-building

I'm interested in building a PC and love Passmark's comparison of processors. What I'm looking for, and have not found, is a similar resource for comparing RAM, motherboards and graphics cards. What are the best resources for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passmark also rates [video cards](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net) and [hard drives](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net) in addition to [processors](http://www.cpubenchmark.net).  While it doesn't give an all in one for RAM and Motherboards, it does maintain a fairly large list of video cards.

Answer (score 1):

[Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/) is a great resource for hardware comparisons, specs, reviews, etc.
[CNet](http://reviews.cnet.com/components/?tag=revCatWrap) is also a great resource for similar information.